# How to update sql column with an array?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've input as `employee` table, `emp_ids` array and `emp_joining_dates` array. My Employee table has 3 columns, `emp_id`, `emp_name` & `emp_joining_date`. Table has more than 10k records. I need to update `emp_joining_date` for `emp_ids` listed in input array.

I was able to achieve this by for-loop, as follows,

```
for 0 < i < emp_ids.length
 update employee set emp_joining_date = emp_joining_dates[i] where emp_id = emp_ids[i] //running update query multiple times
end
```

The problem with above approach is that I'm hitting db with multiple queries. Can I achieve same thing using single query? If yes, how?

**Note**: My question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625673/sql-update-where-in-set-of-data). As I want to update column values with array values, but not by single/static value.

**This question is not related to coding, so please ignore for-loop syntax. It is related to SQL query optimization.**

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially generate a CASE statement like this (assuming you have 3 employees to update):

```
UPDATE employee SET emp_joining_date = CASE emp_id 
    WHEN emp_ids[0] THEN emp_joining_dates[0] 
    WHEN emp_ids[1] THEN emp_joining_dates[1] 
    WHEN emp_ids[2] THEN emp_joining_dates[2] 
END
WHERE emp_id IN (emp_ids[0], emp_ids[1], emp_ids[2])
```

You should test if it actually gives better performance though...

Comment: Not feasible, as `emp_joining_dates` length can vary

Comment: This could work if the SQL was dynamically generated.

Comment: So you're using a client language in which the SQL is not dynamically generated?

Comment: One thought just occured to me: considering the total number of employees and only 365 days in a year, there will be a lot of employees with the same joining date right?

Comment: So you can improve it somewhat by doing a single update per date, updating all employees for that date at once, so
UPDATE employee SET emp_joining_date = the_joining_date WHERE emp_id IN (emp_ids[0], emp_ids[1], emp_ids[2]) 
(the_joining_date would be the joining date of all three employees)

Comment: Of course this will require some additional client-side logic and your language needs to be able to put a varying number of items in the IN clause.

Answer (score 0):

There's two options that I can see immediately (below). I am assuming the joining date is effectively unique for each employee.

## Temp Table and Join

1. Create a temp table containing the IDs and data to be uploaded.
2. Join the two and update the existing table using the temp table.
3. Drop the temp table.

## Batch Updates into Groups

This is the approach provided by André Kops.

## Deal With It :)

The third option is to just accept the thousands of transactions. This might be an unnecessary optimization (though I appreciate that there's always the desire for better code).

Comment: Isn't creating new table & joining equivalent to for loop update?

Comment: Not exactly. You can load a table with a large dataset in one (or maybe a few) transactions. Your transaction count will be smaller than an update for every row. But at the end of the day you can't avoid the fact that you have 10K rows to update each with their own unique values. So either way it's not something you could really reduce by any significant degree.